# object init in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, object, init

```
#import "Page.h"

@implementation Page

-(instancetype)init{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.firstPage =[[Page alloc]init];
        self.choiceA = [[Page alloc]init];
        self.choiceB = [[Page alloc]init];

    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

I'm new to Objective-C.

error: exc_bad_access code=2

What's wrong with my code ? Thanks.

Comment: Does "infinite recursion" ring a bell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is infinite recursion as @HotLicks stated in his comment. If you are new to programming I would recommend reading [this article on recursion](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/). In essence, recursion is when a method calls itself. In your code when you call `[[Page alloc]init]` it is calling `init` ad infinitum subsequently resulting in a stack overflow.